# How to automatically switch Firebase Config based on active project set with 'firebase use'

Tags: reactjs, firebase

When I switch project using `firebase use dev` or `firebase use prod`, before deploying I also currently need to manually switch out the config to use depending on whether it's dev or prod.

How can I automatically detect the firebase project in use to then use the appropriate config? Is there any environment variable or something else containing this information?

```
const firebaseConfigDev = {
  apiKey: "xxx",
  authDomain: "xxx-dev.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "xxx-dev",
  storageBucket: "xxx-dev.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "12345",
  appId: "67890"
};

const firebaseConfigProd = {
  apiKey: "yyy",
  authDomain: "xxx-prod.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "xxx-prod",
  storageBucket: "xxx-prod.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "33333",
  appId: "44444"
};

const app = initializeApp(ZZZ ? firebaseConfigDev : firebaseConfigProd) // what to use in place of ZZZ?
```

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase CLI writes the active project to a `.firebaserc` file. For example, this is the `.firebaserc` in one of my directories:

```
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "iohelper"
  }
}
```

I don't think this file is automatically parsed upon startup by the Firebase core SDK, but you can probably load it yourself and use its contents from there.